# Smallint ou int para PK / Primary Key / chave primária?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, comparação

Em linguagens como o Java, por exemplo, na hora de processar um short int e comparar com outro short int, ambos são transformados em int. O mesmo ocorre em banco de dados como o MySQL?

Comment: Qual a relevância? E não sei se isto ocorre com o Java, tem alguma fonte? Tem consequência?

Answer (score 0):

Os dois tipos citados são inteiros, o que muda é o quanto cada tipo suporta.

**smallint: (2 bytes)** -32768 até +32767 (com sinal) / 0 até 65535 (sem sinal)

**int: (4 bytes)** -2147483648 até +2147483647 (com sinal) / 0 até 4294967295 (sem sinal)

Para saber qual tipo usar como PK, deve ser analisado a quantidade de informações que você vai ter.